# How to add set website in contact editor

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

In my app I have function to add new contact do contacts based on selected item. I'm using new intent to start contact editor with some fields filled. Almost everything is working but I don't know how to add website. 
My code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);        
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY, item.getCompany());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, item.getPhone());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, item.getEmail());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, item.getAddress()); 
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I think you have to use `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);` but have not been able to do it.